# Best practice: Start SESSION handling before or after POST data has been checked

Tags: php, session, post

What is the best practice when it comes to starting **session handling**, `session_start()`. Shall one start it **before** checking **$_POST** data or **after** checking **$_POST** data?

Comment: Ideally, one should start it right before one has to read or write session data.  :P

Comment: My reasoning was to check and confirm any $_POST data before even trigger it. If the $_POST data is valid and true, one could enable the session handling and set whatever is to be set and even HEADER back to same script and if $_POST data is not set, the second check could be if the session has been set. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what your code is doing and how much you care about the $_POST data. I'll discuss some scenarios to help you understand my point.

If the session's existence can offer the user some kind of privilege that should be secured AND the $_POST data contains something that determines whether or not the session is valid, then of course, you need to validate the post data first. For example, you have an `if` statement that just asks "is there a session? If yes, give privileges". If the post data contains the username/pw to validate them, but you've already started a session (given them privileges) then that is obviously bad.

The session itself can exist and not necessarily mean anything as far as privilege (and therefore security). In this case, you may be using the session for some kind of persistent information that ALL visitors have. If someone "logs in", you then add to the session data. In this case, the session exists, but you're simply waiting to validate the username/pw before adding the "logged in" information to the session.

The possibilities are probably extremely vast and I don't think any one answer can apply for every situation. Just be sure to think out all the possibilities and follow standard security practices.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to start it before because I can Check the session for already existing data

Comment: Does not session consume server resources?

Comment: Sessions are temporary files within a server, php is relatively fast when it comes to manipulating them.